# How to sign out using Google Identity API?

Tags: javascript, api, google-signin, google-identity

I have used the Google Identity API to sign in to the user. It works perfectly while signing in.
But the sign-out doesn't work I don't know why.

This is the sign-out code:

```
  const button = document.getElementById('signout_button');
   button.onclick = () => {
   google.accounts.id.disableAutoSelect();
   console.log('logged out');
};
```

But it doesn't work even if press the button.

I want this google box to turn into the button sign in after I sign out but it doesnt work:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You're doing the right thing by calling `disableAutoSelect()` in your sign-out onclick handler, but it only applies to and controls the behavior for the automatic sign-in button. It doesn't affect One Tap or the Sign In With Google button.

To further clarify what it means to be signed in... there are two user sessions:

1. between the user and their Google Account
2. between the user and your app

You'll manage 2, but 1 is not managed by you. For 1 users may be signed into their Google Account from a tab, the browser, or a device/OS. This establishes which Google Account has an active session. The state of this session is independent from 2 where you're managing sign-in or sign-out status for your app.

For case 2: sign-in to your site you'll receive a JWT from Google after user consent and can proceed with changing the sign in state for your app. One means of track sign-in state is using cookies. To make this easier to manage in HTML, the [`data-skip_prompt_cookie`](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference#data-skip_prompt_cookie) attribute is available to enable you to use a cookie to control if the One Tap popup, automatic sign-in option will be displayed, or not. You'd normally want to suppress the popup if the user is signed-in... and the cookie value tracks signed-in status. If you're using JavaScript your simply skip calling [`google.accounts.id.prompt`](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#google.accounts.id.prompt) to not force the user to sign-in again if they're already signed into your site.

OK. Now that we've gone over a couple methods to establish 2. we can get to what it means to be signed out of your site...

To sign-out, from your `button.onclick` handler either clear the `data-skip_prompt_cookie` or change the status if you are using JavaScript to tracking session state using your back end. This then will enable you to display One Tap popup or Automatic sign-in prompt to signed-out users on their return visit to your site.  The absence of the cookie means the sign-in prompts will be displayed, or your JS code will call `google.accounts.id.prompt` to display the sign-in prompts.

Now to be really thorough there is one more scenario to be aware of. If a user wants to delete their account from your site you'll want to use  [google.accounts.id.revoke](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/revoke) to revoke consent to share their profile. Doing this will stop the JWT from being shared when One Tap, automatic sign-in or Sign In With Google buttons are used.  Instead, the flow will restart and the user will be prompted to choose a Google Account and consent--effectively restarting your sign-in flow for 2.